# String reversal in C: What is it I am doing wrong?

Tags: c, string

I am amidst reading K&R C, mainly to brush my C skills, and while attempting to code a program to reverse a given string, and I have a bug that plagues, which, *worst of all, I am unable to debug - nor have a clue what might be the cause of it.*

My code is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * reverse(char *string);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("Please input a string: \t");

    char string[256];

    scanf("%s", string);

    char *reversed = reverse(string);

    printf("The reversed string is %s\n", reversed);

    return 0;
}

char * reverse(char string[])
{
    int size = strlen(string);
    printf("DEBUG: The size of the string that we got as input was: %d\n", size);
    int counter;
    char reversed[size + 1];

    for(counter = size - 1; counter >= 0; counter--) {
        reversed[size - counter] = string[counter];
        printf("DEBUG: The character copied now was %c and was at index %d\n", string[counter], counter);
    }

    reversed[size + 1] = '\0';

    printf("DEBUG: The reversed string is %s\n", reversed);

    return reversed;
}
```

*(Please forgive the debug statements that litter the code logic. Apart from that, feel free to correct any mistake you might see, and also feel free to make suggestions to improve it)*

Now, my code is working (for the most part) but the bug is that it copies characters that I have not input. Below are the (funny) results of two test runs:

The first one:

```
nlightnfotis@crunchbang:~/SoftwareExperiments$ ./reverse
Please input a string:  fotis
DEBUG: The size of the string that we got as input was: 5
DEBUG: The character copied now was s and was at index 4
DEBUG: The character copied now was i and was at index 3
DEBUG: The character copied now was t and was at index 2
DEBUG: The character copied now was o and was at index 1
DEBUG: The character copied now was f and was at index 0
DEBUG: The reversed string is $sitof
The reversed string is $sitof
```

***(Notice the `$`)***

and the second one:

```
nlightnfotis@crunchbang:~/SoftwareExperiments$ ./reverse
Please input a string:  lol
DEBUG: The size of the string that we got as input was: 3
DEBUG: The character copied now was l and was at index 2
DEBUG: The character copied now was o and was at index 1
DEBUG: The character copied now was l and was at index 0
DEBUG: The reversed string is lol
The reversed string is lol
```

More accurately depicted here:

[image: The bug]

Could someone more knowledgeable and experienced than me explain to me what's wrong with my code, or maybe give me a hint as to why I am facing this frustrating bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, annotated with the errors found above plus my own answer:

```
char * reverse(char string[])
{
    int size = strlen(string);
    printf("DEBUG: The size of the string that we got as input was: %d\n", size);
    int counter;

    /* BUGBUG: You are using a stack variable to store the return string.
     * char *reversed = malloc(sizeof(char) * (size + 1))
     * to allocate a string that can be returned safely.
     */
    char reversed[size + 1];

    for(counter = size - 1; counter >= 0; counter--) {
        /* BUGBUG: You are setting the wrong char in "reversed", it should be
         * reversed[size - 1 - counter].  You want the "size - 1" char from the original
         * to be copied to the 0 position of the reversed
         */
        reversed[size - counter] = string[counter];
        printf("DEBUG: The character copied now was %c and was at index %d\n", string[counter], counter);
    }

    /* BUGBUG: You are setting the null character one past the end of the string.
     * Here you want reversed[size], which with 0-indexing is the size+1'st
     * character.
     */
    reversed[size + 1] = '\0';

    printf("DEBUG: The reversed string is %s\n", reversed);

    /* BUGBUG: Just to stress this -- you cannot expect this to work; that it
     * does so is accidental because the call stack is not cleaned.  If the calling
     * function called another function (say printf) then the printf is likely to 
     * overwrite the contents of reversed.
     */
    return reversed;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You are returning a local variable:

```
char * reverse(char string[]) {    
  char reversed[size + 1];
  ....
  return reversed;
}
```

The local variable `reversed` which was allocated on the stack, ceases to exist once the function `reverse` returns. So any reference to it from `main` leads to undefined behavior.

To fix this you can do either of the following:

1. Make the function `void` and modify the input array.
2. Declare the array `reversed` as static so that its lifetime changes to the lifetime of the program.
3. Dynamically allocate (and later de-allocate) `reversed`

Comment: Could you elaborate some more on why this is an issue? I only got a warning from gcc, and as you can see, the `DEBUG` statement inside that function also demonstrates that behavior.

Comment: The variable being local isn't a problem. It being *automatic* is.

Comment: Guys, guys, I am not blind, and I can read compiler output. I knew that was an issue, be it small or big. **You see, the thing I have issues with is the `DEBUG` statement inside the function, way before control returns to `main`.**

Answer (score 8):

Always the very same errors, over and over...

I.

```
char reversed[size + 1];
// ...
return reversed;
```

You're returning an automatic array, which is out of scope as soon as the function returns - undefined behavior. Make `reversed` a `static` variable to avoid this (then read up on the `static` keyword before you start to believe it's magic).

II.

```
char string[256];
scanf("%s", string);
```

Potential buffer overrun and bug when entering strings with spaces in them. Change this to

```
fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin);
```

III.

```
char reversed[size + 1];
// ...
reversed[size + 1] = '\0';
```

Another buffer overrun. In C, arrays are indexed from 0.

---

Time to read a good C book.

Comment: One more issue even -- the copy is copying string[counter] into reversed[size-counter].  So reversed[0] will not be set.  Should be reversed[size - 1 - counter].

Comment: @user295691 That solved my issue just fine. I am inviting you to post an answer to the question with what you said which I will also mark as the accepted one.

Answer (score 3):

Besides codaddict's post and H2CO3's nice explanation, you have one more error:

```
 char reversed[size + 1];
 reversed[size + 1] = '\0';
```

this will result in index of out bound. say `size = 10`, then `size +1 =11`. index values of char array `reversed` are
`0,1,2,3,...,10`.  Therefore, `reversed[11]`  will be get you in trouble.

Comment: +1 That's a nice one I hadn't noticed at first. Or it might have just slipped during my various tests. Nice one anyway.

Comment: @NlightNFotis: This will fix your debug statement inside the function.